# VBA word, Delete between first and second instances in every paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

In VBA word, I have a document, with this text below, and i need a vba macro to loop it and delete 
"**| unwanted_text**" 
from every line , anyone can help me please?

example1 **| unwanted_text** | example2 | example3 | example4 
hello world 
example1 **| unwanted_text** | example2 | example3 | example4 
hello world 
The final result must be like this:

example1 | example2 | example3 | example4 
hello world 
example1 | example2 | example3 | example4 
hello world 
Note: **unwanted_text** could be any variable string

Comment: Either you need to define exactly what "| unwanted text" will actually be or you need to explain the rules for how to find. Is it delimited by "|"? If so, will there *always* be the proper delimiters?

Comment: Are you trying to do the equivalent of Word's "Replace All", where "Find what:" is whatever you specify, and "Replace with:" is an empty string?  This doesn't seem to fit with the question title of "Delete between first and second instances in every paragraph".

Comment: loop over the text: if the second and fourth words are "|" then delete the second and third words.

Comment: Are each of your lines terminated with a paragraph mark? Will your 'words' be delimited by spaces? Note that 'unwanted_text'appears to Word VBA as *three* words (yes, it counts the underscore as a word). If you can guarantee there will only be one true word, then it's simple. Else, if always delimited by spaces, then still easy.

Comment: Yes,  it's just one word, and all if them are delimited by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will:
(a) spin thru your document
(b) determine if the pattern is found
(c) delete the 2nd and 3rd words if pattern is found.

```
    Sub Delete_Words()
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If oPara.Range.Words.Count > 3 Then

            ' You can check for specific values of word 2 and 4
            ' Then could delete whatever is between
            'Debug.Print oPara.Range.Words(2).Text & " <> " & oPara.Range.Words(4).Text
            If Trim(oPara.Range.Words(2).Text) = "|" And Trim(oPara.Range.Words(4).Text) = "|" Then
                ' NOTE!! Must delete word 3 before word 2, else incorrect results!
                oPara.Range.Words(3).Delete
                oPara.Range.Words(2).Delete
            End If
        Else
            ' Not enough words
        End If
    Next
    Exit Sub
Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print "Error: " ^ Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    MsgBox "Error: " ^ Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
End Sub
```